# basename with spaces in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, scripting

I'm working on a bash script to create a new folder in /tmp/ using the name of a file, and then copy the file inside that folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

MYBASENAME="`basename $1`"
mkdir "/tmp/$MYBASENAME"

for ARG in "$@"
    do
        mv "$ARG" "/tmp/$MYBASENAME"

done
```

Behavior:

When I type in `mymove "/home/me/downloads/my new file.zip"` it shows this:

```
mkdir /tmp/my
new
file.zip
mv: rename /home/me/downloads/my new file.zip to /tmp/my\nnew\nfile.zip:
```

I have lots of quotes around everything, so I don't understand why this is not working as expected.

Also, I have the form loop in there in case there are multiple files. I want them all to be copied to the same folder, based on the first argument's basename.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the case where the assignment is a single command substitution you do not need to quote the command substitution. The shell does not perform word splitting for variable assignments.

```
MYBASENAME=$(basename "$1")
```

is all it takes. You should get into the habit of using `$()` instead of backticks because `$()` nests more easily (it's POSIX, btw., and all modern shells support it.)

PS: You should try to **not** write **bash** scripts. Try writing **shell** scripts. The difference being the absence of bashisms, zshisms, etc. Just like for C, portability is a desired feature of scripts, especially if it can be attained easily. Your script does not use any bashisms, so I'd write `#!/bin/sh` instead. For the nit pickers: Yes, I know, old SunOS and Solaris `/bin/sh` do not understand `$()` but the `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` is a POSIX shell.

Comment: i noticed a lot of the default shell scripts use sh instead of bash. i still can't tell too much of a difference, except with things like `echo \c` to keep a new line from appearing. thanks for the tips and helpful answer.

Comment: The portable way with echo \c is to use `printf` where you just omit the `\n` in the format string. The most often used bashisms arguably are the use of array variables, non-POSIX syntax like `[[ ... ]]` for tests, for loops with `for (( ... ))`, and the `select` construct.

Comment: This does not work with bash shipped on my macosx lion (GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)

Comment: @rjha94 What exactly does not work? What is the result? Please be very specific.

Comment: @jens my bad, I had forgotten "quotes" around the name

Comment: ~/code/misc $ cat basename.sh 
#!/bin/sh
MYBASENAME=$(basename "$1") ;
echo $MYBASENAME ;

 ~/code/misc $ ./basename.sh "/usr/path with space/xyz"
xyz

Comment: @Jens, I'm sorry about unintended downvoting.  I meant to be upvoting.  Could you edit your post a little bit so that I could undo my careless downvote.  Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `$1` in

```
MYBASENAME="`basename $1`"
```

is not quoted. Use this instead:

```
MYBASENAME="$(basename "$1")"
```

Comment: +1 for using $() form of command substitution. Folks unless you're really, really sure that you'll be using a system that only has the bourne shell, why not upgrade your technology syntax to 1993 standards ;-) ! I bet you use `sed -i` without thinking about it. But you won't find `sed -i` on systems that rely on bourne shell, or a 100 other gnu/linux-isms. Good luck to all. <End PetPeeveRant />

Answer (score 3):

You're missing one set of quotes!

```
MYBASENAME="`basename \"$1\"`"
```

That'll fix your problem.

Comment: You're writing one pair of quotes and backslashes too much :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am just copying what's from [[SOLVED] mv: target `filename' is not a directory](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/mv-target-%60filename%27-is-not-a-directory-745600/); credit to the original responder:

> Add this to the start of your script. It changes the internal field
> separator to a newline only, and your script will treat spaces as just
> another character from then on.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='
'

<your script>
```

This Wikipedia page tells more about the special shell variable: [Internal field separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator).

Answer (score 0):

```
MYBASENAME="`basename $1`"
```

should be

```
MYBASENAME="`basename "$1"`"
```

Wrap the `$1` with double quotes `"$1"`